# Conflicting class names imported from jars in jruby

Tags: jar, jruby

I'm working on a JRuby (on Rails) project that is depending on various java libraries, imported as jars. Unfortunately, the class name and path of some of the classes I'd like to use are exactly the same in two libraries.

How can I solve this conflict and specify in every case precisely which class from which jar I want? Or can I include a library scoped?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can put them into packages. For example, in you `library1.jar`, you would put `package com.lib1` or something like that. Then, you could import it with `import com.lib1.library1`.

Comment: That would be the trivial solution. But what if these jars are both external dependencies, so I don't have access to it's source code and can not change it?